# Handling unnecessary API calls in Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a set of information to be displayed as per the role. I have used ng-show to show the relevant info(fetched from an API ) to the respective role, i want to restrict the calls to API which are not necessary for the role.I have tried an if condition but that's not helping. Can someone enlighten me ?

Comment: Please post any relevant code

Comment: @FuriousD `<p ng-show="admin">{{data}}</p>

<p ng-show="user">{{data}}</p>`  

both api calls are on the same controller ,only on view im showing it by ng-show="role. will i have to make a separate controller?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering data according to the role should be done server side on the API not on the client side using Angular because the user can simply view source or inspect the traffic to see the data.

Comment: yes Haitham, the data is filtered as per the role on serverside. My scenario is I'm displaying data on a dashboard. currently im just showing the data  using ng-show according to the role. So its the same dashboard view ,im just hiding the other role data (on the view) but the API is being called. Only on the view, the data is hidden but behind the scenes the  API is being called. how restrict the calls to API which are not necessary for the role when im hiding the data on view. Do i have to make a separate view for different views?

Comment: You should have a service that tells you the user role, and according to that role, inside the controller class, only calls the API related to the current role. If the dashboards are different, you can then make it separate views